# rev-manifest и watch | Gulp

Tags: gulp

Есть два таска - `build:scss` и `build:js`:

```
gulp.task('build:scss', function () {
return gulp.src(paths.src.scss)
    .pipe(scss({
        includePaths: includePaths.scss
    }))
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/build'))
    .pipe(rev.manifest({
        path: 'public/build/rev-manifest.json',
        merge: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(''));
});

gulp.task('build:js', function () {
return gulp.src(paths.src.js)
    .pipe(rigger())
    .pipe(rename('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/build'))
    .pipe(rev.manifest({
        path: 'public/build/rev-manifest.json',
        merge: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(''))
});
```

Так же есть вотчер:

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  watch([paths.watch.scss], function () {
    gulp.start('build:scss');
  });
  watch([paths.watch.js], function () {
    gulp.start('build:js');
  });
});
```

**Задача**: создание ревизий css и js файлов и запись их имен в rev-manifest.json (все это в вызовах watch'еров)

**Текущий результат**: все отрабатывает, но если изменить scss и js и сохранить, то в rev-manifest не пишется один из них (в моем случае - css)

Как я понимаю, тут вопрос в синхронизации доступа на запись к файлу rev-manifest. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать?

Так же, дабы не создавать новый вопрос, подскажите, как быть со старыми файлами ревизий? Сейчас написана своя функция, но... Наверняка есть правильный подход - хотелось бы узнать.

P.S. добавил `gulp-sync` в `build` таск - работает норм, но не решает проблем с вотчерами. А запускать билд и js и scss при изменении одного из файлов - наверняка не очень хорошее решение.
P.P.S. Так же пробовал играться с `gulp-queue`, однако, как я понял, это не совсем то.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, после нескольких дней страданий решение найдено:

1. Плагин [gulp-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sync) позволяет синхронно запускать таски.
2. От плагина **gulp-rev** я отказался в пользу [gulp-rev-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rev-all)
3. Сборку/компиляцию js/scss я вынес в отдельный таск (названия **js**/**scss**)
4. Генерацию **rev-manifest** тоже вынес в отдельный таск (там же и функция, удаляющая папку **build** со старыми файлами - ручками написана, не плагин)
5. Создал два новых таска: **build:scss** и **build:js**. Они с помощью **gulpSync** запускают последовательное выполнение **scss**/**js** и затем **manifest**.

**Суть:** ранее хотел обойтись без сохранения неревизионных файлов (без хэша в имени). Сейчас же, после сборки/компиляции, файлы помещаются во временную папку - условно **tmp** - которая в гитигноре.

На каждое изменение scss/js таск **manifest** будет удалять старую **build** папку и создавать все заново (файлы с хешом + записи в **rev-manifest**).

Мы попрежнему проигрываем в случае изменения js и scss + полный билд: таск-менеджер дважды проделает одинаковую работу: удаление и создание новых файлов.

Тем не менее, решение работает. Если Вы знаете более правильный подход - пожалуйста, отпишитесь сдесь. Буду очень признателен.

Немного кода (в общих чертах):

```
gulp.task('scss', function () {
return gulp.src(paths.src.scss)
    .pipe(scss({
        includePaths: includePaths.scss
    }))
    .pipe(rename('app.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.tmpFront));
});

gulp.task('build:scss', gulpSync.sync(['scss', 'manifest']));


gulp.task('js', function () {
return gulp.src(paths.src.js)
    .pipe(rigger())
    .pipe(rename('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.tmpFront));
});

gulp.task('build:js', gulpSync.sync(['js', 'manifest']));


gulp.task('manifest', function () {
deleteOldRevisions();

return gulp.src(paths.tmpFront + '**/*')
    .pipe(revAll.revision())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.build.dest))
    .pipe(revAll.manifestFile())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.build.dest));
});
```

**P.S.** Более правильным решением будет организовать очередь тасков, что я и пытался сделать с помощью [gulp-queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-queue), но, увы, то ли моя криворукость, то ли разработчиков плагина помешала этому: в файл манифест не прописывался один из пустей (тот, который отрабатывал вторым). Почему так - я не понял. Возможно у Вас получится реализовать очередь - опять же был бы признателен :)

**UPD:** можно и не костылить свои чудо-функции удаления: плагин [del](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del)